# OpenNTF Domino API - best way to get started

Tags: java, xpages

I managed to get the OpenNTF Domino API installed on one of our servers (version 4.0.0). Now I am wondering what would be the easiest way for me to get acquainted with it, in other words how can I learn from as much examples as quickly and easiest as possible?

Comment: Do you have a lot of Java code already?  If you do, you could go for the hard core route of replace all "import lotus.domino." refs to "import org.openntf.domino.".  Don't do that with lotus.domino.NotesException.  This will give you a lot of errors and thus a really good way of learning.

Answer (score 4):

There's an NSF version in my session slides from ICON UK a couple of years ago [here](http://www.intec.co.uk/session-slides-from-icon-uk-and-openntf-domino-api-demo-database/).

The more recent version is as an OSGi plugin (deploy it the same as ODA itself), in a separate project on [OpenNTF](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API%20Demo%20Database/summary). It's rather large because it's built with Vaadin and includes the relevant JAR files for that. It includes more detailed background and is aimed less at comparisons of core Domino functions and more at areas of note and what methods are new. It requires an instance of Extension Library demo database at "extlibnew/xpagesext.nsf" (it uses this as a template for creating ten more in "odademo_osgi"). The Ext Lib demo database also needs a couple of minor modifications, outlined in the documentation.

Here's the latest session I did on it, with Stephan Wissel at IBM Connect last month https://www.slideshare.net/paulswithers1/openntf-domino-api-oda-supercharging-domino-development. It gives lots of information.

There's also a TLCC webinar I did with Jesse and Nathan last year https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szbz6REdKDU&feature=youtu.be.

I intend to start doing some short videos soon, covering individual snippets of functionality.

On OpenNTF Slack there is an ODA channel, where all the developers are active, so that's also a good place to discuss things / pick up new things or answers to other queries.